# I have British passport transit time from Sydney flight to London 8 hours 5 mins do I need transit visa?

Tags: transit, australia, uk-citizens

Do I need transit visa for 8 hrs 5 mins transit time at Sydney for flight to London Heathrow?

Comment: If you are in-bound to Sydney as a British citizen, then flying to Heathrow you do not need a visa and you can happily spend the transit time however it pleases you.

Comment: I read this as the OP is transiting in Sydney.

Answer (score 4):

As a holder of a British passport, you will need either a [Transit Visa](http://www.border.gov.au/Trav/Visa-1/771-) or [an electronic visa](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/australia/entry-requirements) (eVisitor).

Your eight hours five minute transit time causes to fall afoul of [the rules allowing transit without visa](http://www.border.gov.au/Lega/Lega/Form/Immi-FAQs/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-through-australia):

> Travellers must:
>
> - enter Australia by aircraft
> - **hold a confirmed onward booking to leave Australia to travel to a third country on the same or another aircraft within 8 hours of arrival in Australia**
> - hold documentation necessary to enter the country of destination
>   and
> - not need to leave the airport transit lounge except to continue their journey.